# Race condition using multiprocessing and threading together

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I wrote the sample program.
It creates 8 threads and spawns process in each one

```
import threading
from multiprocessing import Process

def fast_function():
    pass

def thread_function():
    process_number = 1
    print 'start %s processes' % process_number
    for i in range(process_number):
        p = Process(target=fast_function, args=())
        p.start()
        p.join()

def main():
    threads_number = 8
    print 'start %s threads' % threads_number
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=()) 
            for i in range(threads_number)]

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

It crashes with several exceptions like this

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "./repeat_multiprocessing_bug.py", line 15, in thread_function
    p.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in start
    _cleanup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 53, in _cleanup
    if p._popen.poll() is not None:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 106, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
OSError: [Errno 10] No child processes
```

Python version 2.6.5. Can somebody explain what I do wrong?

Comment: For what it worth, it works fine under `Windows` with `Python 2.6.4` and Linux with `Python 2.7.2`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to run it from the interactive interpreter. Try writing your code to a file and run it as a python script, it works on my machine...

See the explanation and examples at the [Python multiprocessing docs](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: I do as you described and it doesn't work. Threads and Process works correctly when they are used separatly.
My current version - this is bug in python

Answer (score 1):

The multiprocessing module has a thread-safety issue in 2.6.5. Your best bet is updating to a newer Python, or add this patch to 2.6.5: http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/41aef062d529/

The bug is described in more detail in the following links:

- http://bugs.python.org/issue11891
- http://bugs.python.org/issue1731717